# No isomorphism between set of finite and infinite sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-space-isomorphism

I have this in my notes and now I can't remember why that's the case:
If $V$ is the set of finite sequences (i.e. finitely many non-zero entries) and $V'$ is the set of infinite sequences, then $V$ is not isomorphic to $V'$. 
I was thinking along the line that the first one has a countable basis (1 in entry n and zero everywhere else) and the second one doesn't, but I'm not sure if this works and also can't formalise it. 
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, if the set of elements is finite (but at least 2) or countable, then there are a countably infinite number of finite sequences and an uncountably infinite number of infinite sequences. Cantor's diagonalization argument shows that an isomorphism doesn't exist (which is why we know there are uncountable infinities in the first place).

Comment: thank you @aschepler